# How to use thrust bearing with shaft?

Tags: motor, mechanism

I know how to use radial bearings, e.g. ball bearings with shaft. But no matter how much I googled I didn't find any proper clear way to use thrust/axial bearing with shaft.

I downloaded the thrust bearing models and checked its upper and bottom diameter and it is same. I'm really confused right now. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: think of a turntable in a microwave oven